# Where is chrome.storage.local stored for Chrome Apps?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-yosemite, google-chrome-app

Where is `chrome.storage.local` stored for Chrome Apps in OSX yosemite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local App Settings/{{chrome-app-id}}`. The whole `{{chrome-app-id}}` folder is a `leveldb` database. I was able to open it and inspect the contents of the stored file using the [leveldb-ruby gem](https://github.com/wmorgan/leveldb-ruby). Just do the following

```
require 'leveldb'
db = LevelDB:DB.new '~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local App Settings/{{chrome-app-id}}'
```

You can now query the database using the `db` object. By the way if you get a weird error saying that the db is being used by someone else make sure you kill chrome and erase the `LOCK` file.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is located in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage`. You'll need the ID to find the correct files but they'll be prefixed with `chrome-` and have a file extension of `.localstorage`.

Based on some picking through the POSTMan App, it looks like it makes a call to `chrome.storage.local` and the data on my Mac is located here: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local App Settings/<ID>/000003.log`.

Comment: I think those are where `localStorage` is saved, not `chrome.storage.local`

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'll update with some more research.

Comment: I found it under `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local App Settings/{{chrome-app-id}}` could you confirm this under your environment?

Comment: @fernandohur Found it there too. The contents of that directory are strange and mysterious.